# Installing TexturePacker in Travis CI

Tags: macos, unix, terminal, travis-ci, texturepacker

I'm trying to install TexturePacker inside Travis CI. The following four commands all run fine and return exit code 0 on my mac.

```
language: objective-c

install:
- hdiutil attach -mountpoint dmg client/TexturePacker-3.2.1-uni.dmg
- cp -Ra dmg/TexturePacker.app .
- hdiutil detach dmg
- echo agree | TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS/TexturePacker --version &> /dev/null
```

On Travis however the following error occurs.

The command "echo agree | TexturePacker.app/Contents/MacOS/TexturePacker --version &> /dev/null" failed and exited with 10 during .

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

TexturePacker 3.2.1 doesn't support agreement via terminal. The solution is upgrade TexturePacker, 3.6.0 worked.